# Add marker and onclick function to show infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know this is simple but it's really hard to add this for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
    });
    var marker;

    function createMarker(latlng, html) {
        var contentString = html;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 1.4683625, lng: 124.8308826},
            zoom: 15
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

// Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                map.setCenter(pos);

                createMarker(map.getCenter(), "The marker is here");

            }, function () {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
// Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
```

So far I try to join it with this code :

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});

function createMarker(latlng, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```

But I cant get that working, It just show some image without infowindow or anything. How to add Marker and show infowindow only when I click the marker?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [examples in the google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3)?

Comment: yes, but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map` variable is local to the `initMap` function, so is not accessible inside the `createMarker` function.

**code snippet:**

```js
// global map variable
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

function createMarker(latlng, html) {
  var contentString = html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function initMap(response) {
  // initialize the global version of the map variable, don't create a new one local to this function
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 1.4683625,
      lng: 124.8308826
    },
    zoom: 15
  });
  createMarker(map.getCenter(), "The marker is here");
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: okay, based on your code I made some adjusment and it almost work I can show the marker now, It's clickable but only showing infowindow once after it close it's unable to open again, please help in my update question. Actually I'm trying to make it in 1 piece of code cause later will be combine with reverse geocode to get address based on location lat lng and get that address to become php variable (of course in different question)

Comment: I don't see you using the `createMarker` function.

Comment: yes, cause in my code lat and lon are obtained from location (html 5 geolocation) and it always change. while the map center always be in that coordinat. that's why I only took your google.maps.Marker and  google.maps.event.addListener. Any Solution?

Comment: Maybe use the createMariker function?

Comment: but how to use createMarker() while getting lat lon from geolocation?

Comment: Make a `google.maps.LatLng` as its first argument (or remove the dependency on `latlng.lat()`, that probably isn't required, but it was in the code you posted...).  Edited my answer to remove that dependency, you should be able to pass a `google.maps.LatLngLiteral` into `createMarker` now.

Comment: I already used createMarker() now I have no marker shown (updated code in question)

Comment: Your map variable is local to the `initMap` function, make it global (as my answer specifies).

Comment: Nice one (I forgot about that javascript lesson about global thing). Ok, now marker are shown but infoWindow are not shown when clicked, how to resolve this?

Comment: The code in your question works for me (with an extra empty infowindow in the upper left corner).  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lb1fwnfg/2/)

Comment: in fiddle are working, but in my program are not working is it because I dont use library? I have this code in last line :
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myapikey&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer>
</script>

Comment: I don't know.  The fiddle has the code from your question in it.  If you are asynchronously loading the API, you will need to add all the code that depends on the API inside the `initMap` function (like the initialization of the global `infowindow`).

Comment: I already delete that global infoWindow, but still it's not working, can you show me how? that last line are copied directly from google. I just need this script to run each time I refresh the page.

Comment: I really dont understand, I just leave that code untouched for 5 minutes (with global infoWindow re-added again but still have same error tested on 4 browser with clear cache and everything before tested) and suddenly it woorrrrrkkksssss.... thank you geocode... by the way that zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5 are taken from one of sample code from your website. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you might have had an older version stuck in a cache somewhere.

Comment: yes I just realize have an issue on chrome, somehow it wont clear it's cache and get position, and before that I did move the script to the head part (I'm using laravel and some master layout). Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a error in script. You must replace `latlng.lat()` with `latlng.lat`.

Another error I can think of is `map` variable is local so it can't be used in `createMarker`. You need to move it to global scope.

```
var map = null;
function initMap(response) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 1.4683625, lng: 124.8308826},
        zoom: 15
    });
    ...
}
```